# adding generic services in asp.net core DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

in asp.net core DI, with the following:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class {}
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T:class {}
```

I'll do the following to register my sevices:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

but now I have my service like the the following:

```
public interface IContextProvider<T1,T2> {}
public class ContextProviderOne<T2> : IContextProvider<ContextClass1,T2> { }
public class ContextProviderTwo<T2> : IContextProvider<ContextClass2,T2> { }
```

how will I add my services to the DI?

Comment: How is `services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(IRepository<>));` supposed to work, `IRepository<>` can't be instantiated, it's an interface, not a concrete class.

Comment: You mean to say that the following registration doesn't work with the built-in container? `services.AddScoped(typeof(IContextProvider<,>), typeof(ContextProviderOne<>)); services.AddScoped(typeof(IContextProvider<,>), typeof(ContextProviderTwo<>));`?

Comment: @Tseng: That's obviously a typo.

Comment: It says `An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.ArgumentException: The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
Parameter name: instantiation`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IContextProvider<T1>), typeof(ContextProviderOne<T1>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IContextProvider<T2>), typeof(ContextProviderTwo<T2>));
```